Trouble building a LEGO gearbox
I have tried many times to make a 6+N+R gearbox, but all I can find are people with many clutch gears, driving rings, and other special parts, such as the change-over catch. I want to make a compact 6+N+R manual gearbox.

Have you seen this model?

I found this here by searching for "Lego gearbox" on Google.
Admittedly, it could be much more compact, but it doesn't use any specialized pieces or illegal building techniques.
Or if you're okay with illegal connections, but need the gearbox to be more compact, you could consider this diagonal gearbox concept (see in operation here):


Of course, you'd need to add a reverse gear to this model, but that should be manageable.
Other videos for the gearboxes without driving rings and clutch gears (Mostly legal):
Sariel's 5-speed gearbox
Sariel's 2-speed automatic gearbox
Sariel's 3-speed Servo gearbox

Thank you! That worked well, and adding a reverse isn’t too hard
